# i keep encountering deprecated files form github and useless youtube videos that intend to scam viewers-- can anyone help?

Tags: nft, mint

currently working on developing my first solana nft. i have generated the art and meta data  and uploaded the files to arweave however every metaplex candymachine have encountered has ultimately been problematic. can anyone recommend a tutorial or share advice on how to use a candy-machine and bundlr to upload my images, metadata, and smartcontract to a mint dapp where they can be sold.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the SolDev web holds a lot of interesting material for beginners. The Tutorials section might be a good place to look for the resources that best suit your needs.

https://soldev.app

https://soldev.app/library/tutorials